# How to pass Azure Auth when Deploying NuGet Package via Nuke.Common/NuGet.CommandLine

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops, nuget, nuke-build

I'm attempting to automate NuGet Package updates through Nuke and CI/CD on Azure DevOps. Everything is building just fine, but during the PushNuGet step, the process tries to authenticate with Azure via a pop-up window, which is obviously never rendered [in devops] or answered

```
class Build : NukeBuild
{
    /// Support plugins are available for:
    ///   - JetBrains ReSharper        https://nuke.build/resharper
    ///   - JetBrains Rider            https://nuke.build/rider
    ///   - Microsoft VisualStudio     https://nuke.build/visualstudio
    ///   - Microsoft VSCode           https://nuke.build/vscode

    public static int Main () => Execute<Build>(x => x.PushNuGet);

    [Parameter("Configuration to build - Default is 'Debug' (local) or 'Release' (server)")]
    readonly Configuration Configuration = IsLocalBuild ? Configuration.Debug : Configuration.Release;

    [Solution] readonly Solution Solution;
    [GitRepository] readonly GitRepository GitRepository;

    AbsolutePath SourceDirectory => RootDirectory / "src";
    AbsolutePath TestsDirectory => RootDirectory / "tests";
    AbsolutePath ArtifactsDirectory => RootDirectory / "artifacts";

    string VersionNumber = "1.0.2";

    Target Clean => _ => _
        .Executes(() =>
        {
            SourceDirectory.GlobDirectories("**/bin", "**/obj").ForEach(DeleteDirectory);
            TestsDirectory.GlobDirectories("**/bin", "**/obj").ForEach(DeleteDirectory);
            EnsureCleanDirectory(ArtifactsDirectory);
        });

    Target Restore => _ => _
        .DependsOn(Clean)
        .Executes(() =>
        {
            DotNetRestore(s => s
                .SetProjectFile(Solution));
        });

    Target Compile => _ => _
        .DependsOn(Restore)
        .Executes(() =>
        {
            DotNetBuild(s => s
                .SetProjectFile(Solution)
                .SetConfiguration(Configuration)
                .EnableNoRestore());
        });

    Target Pack => _ => _
        .DependsOn(Compile)
        .Executes(() =>
        {
            DotNetPack(s => s
                .SetProject(RootDirectory + "\\Fuze.Models\\Fuze.Models.csproj")
                .SetNoBuild(true)
                .SetConfiguration(Configuration)    
                .SetVersion(VersionNumber)
            );
        });

    Target AddSource => _ => _
       .DependsOn(Pack)
       .Executes(() =>
       {
            var sourceUrl = "https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/DataFuzionHCM/_packaging/DataFuzionHCM/nuget/v3/index.json";
            var sourceName = "DataFuzionHCM";
            var sources = NuGetTasks.NuGetSourcesList();
            if(sources.Any(source => source.Text.Contains(sourceName)))
            {
               NuGetTasks.NuGetSourcesRemove(s => s.SetName(sourceName));
            }
            NuGetTasks.NuGetSourcesAdd(s => s
                .SetName(sourceName)
                .SetSource(sourceUrl)
                .SetUserName("NuGet Feed Token")
                .SetPassword("fakepassword")
            );
       });

    Target PushNuGet => _ => _
        .DependsOn(AddSource)
        .Executes(() =>
        {
            NuGetTasks.NuGetPush(s => s
                .SetSource("DataFuzionHCM")
                .SetApiKey("az")
                .SetTargetPath(RootDirectory + $"/FUZE.Models/bin/debug/Fuze.Models.{VersionNumber}.nupkg")
            );
        });
}
```

On the Azure Build Pipeline, During the last step, it can be seen in the job log that it's getting stuck on some auth window with azure.

```
Using credentials from config. UserName: NuGet Feed Token
    [CredentialProvider]Using the ADAL UI  flow for uri https://pkgs.dev.[hidden]ure.com/DataFuzionHCM/_packaging/DataFuzionHCM/nuget/v3/index.json. User sign-in required in a pop-up authentication window.
    [CredentialProvider]Using the ADAL UI  flow for uri https://pkgs.dev.[hidden]ure.com/DataFuzionHCM/_packaging/DataFuzionHCM/nuget/v3/index.json. User sign-in required in a pop-up authentication window.
    [CredentialProvider]Using the ADAL UI  flow for uri https://pkgs.dev.[hidden]ure.com/DataFuzionHCM/_packaging/DataFuzionHCM/nuget/v3/index.json. User sign-in required in a pop-up authentication window.
##[error]Unable to load the service index for source https://pkgs.dev.[hidden]ure.com/DataFuzionHCM/_packaging/DataFuzionHCM/nuget/v3/index.json.
##[error]  The HTTP request to 'GET https://pkgs.dev.[hidden]ure.com/DataFuzionHCM/_packaging/DataFuzionHCM/nuget/v3/index.json' has timed out after 100000ms.
##[error]Process 'NuGet.exe' exited with code 1.
```

Is there a method to programmatically authenticate with Azure so it doesn't hang and timeout at the popup-auth?

Comment: Hi, Could you check the proxy settings into Nuget.Config file and then share the result here? Refer to this link for details: [Nuget Config Section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file#config-section) and [Nuget Proxy Settings](http://skolima.blogspot.com/2012/07/nuget-proxy-settings.html). By the way, what happens if you run locally?

Comment: When I ran it locally, a prompt window would appear for me to auth to azure. Entering my personal credentials allowed the request to pass - I posted the resolution to my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that the password for the NuGet feed was expired, so when auth failed, it prompted for auth instead of throwing an auth error.
I went into DevOps and updated the expiration date on the password and, from there, everything worked fine.

I do find it odd that instead of throwing an auth error, it instead asks for a password from the local user on a separate window. Perhaps automation wasn't something that was taken into account when the API's for updating NuGet packages were designed.

Comment: Hi @Chris Phillips, Thanks for your sharing, you could accept your answer. In this case, others could directly find the useful solution. Thanks